# shared pointer isn't working when casting?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

casting shared pointer from B class to A class is not working the console output isn't 12 it's (it outputs A's x but i want B's x)(probably an other memory address). what's wrong with my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){}
    B(const B*){}
    int x = 12;
};

std::shared_ptr<A> create()
{
    return std::make_shared<B>(new B);
}

int main(){

   std::shared_ptr<A> p;
   p = create();
   std::cout << p->x << std::endl;

   std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `x` in `A` is never initialized.

Comment: but i want it to point B's x

Comment: Unrelated to the issue you asked about, but you're leaking a `B` object.  In general, `std::make_shared<T>(new T)` is almost always wrong.

Comment: having a member variable in a derived class with same name of a member variable in its base class is always a bad idea. here you are experiencing why.
in this scenario, each B instance has got two variables with same name, `B::x` and `A::x`, you think your code should print `B::x`, but it actually prints `A::x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A::x` and `B::x` are different objects.  Variable access is never polymorphic in C++, so when you access `p->x`, you're accessing `A::x`.  `A::x` was never initialized though, so the behavior of your program is undefined.

You need to either have your derived class's constructor initialize the base class's object or delegate that responsibility to the base class's constructor:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int x) : x{x} {}
    int x;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A{12} {}
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/358250dc887660f9)

---

Alternatively you could wrap `x` in a `virtual` accessor method:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual int x() const = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    int x() const override
    {
        return x_;
    }
private:
    int x_ = 12;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4418f57dc35b4a64)